# Sign In With Google - One Tap close callback?

Tags: javascript, callback, sdk, google-signin

Google has recently announced its [deprecation of its Google Sign-In for Websites library](https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/08/gsi-jsweb-deprecation.html). They will be transitioning to the new Sign In With Google SDK for the Web in 2023. The new SDK requires less effort to set up, but I find there are fewer settings available for configuration.

One of the configurations that I am missing is the detection for user closing the One Tab Sign In Pop up. Previously, when the user manually closes the Sign In modal, the library returns the `popup_closed_by_user` [error code](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#error_codes_2). But I am not able to find any detection for this on the new JavaScript Web SDK.

Is there a way to detect the manual pop up closing on the [Sign In With Google SDK](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#ux_mode)?
I am also interested on detecting ["Exponential cooldown"](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/features#exponential_cooldown). That is, when user has closed the pop-up multiple times and Google SDK won't show the login button on the screen. Is it possible to trigger a callback when this case occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can observe the outcome using the [PromptMomentNotification](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#PromptMomentNotification) object, using the [data-moment_callback](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#data-moment_callback) when rendering the button in HTML or by throught the notification returned by [google.accounts.id.prompt](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#google.accounts.id.prompt).

One tap can be closed a couple of ways, so the older `popup_closed_by_user` is now best handled by looking at two values:
`user_cancel` or `tap_outside`. The former is a result of pressing the X in the dialog or cancel button if present, while the latter is from simply clicking outside of the popup dialog. Both terminate the sign-in flow, the two values allow you to see if user behavior differs. Some users might click elsewhere, while others may explicitly close the popup.

Comment: Unfortunately I did never get a close notification when the popup window was closed when using the one-tap javascript library. To be precise, I mean the real popup window that appears when you call `google.accounts.id.renderButton` and then click on the button with no existing session (logged out of your google account). Would appreciate help if somebody knows why.

Comment: There are two UI sign-in options: the Sign In With Google button and the One tap popup. Only the One tap popup returns a PromptMomentNotification when displayed by calling google.accounts.id.prompt(). When using renderButton to display the sign-in button you will not receive a prompt callback. Put another way, renderButton is not expected to fail and is always displayed so no response is returned.